# how can I multiply 2 numbers using right shifting?

Tags: binary, computer-science

I have been searching about this for hours and still I cant figure it out.
I want to multiply these two numbers:(not sign numbers)
101011 * 110010 = ?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you can decompose A in a sum of powers of 2 (100000 + 1000 + 10 + 1). Each of them represents a shift for B, so, you can follow the next steps:

1. Check the right-most bit of A. If is 0, do nothing. If is 1, add B to the result (initially 0).
2. Shift A to the right.
3. Shift B to the left.
4. Repeat until A = 0.

There are other ways to do it. For example, changing the step 3 by: Shift the result (circular shift) to the right.

Notice that the result must have twice of the bits of A and B in order to get the exact result.